# reading a string from input file SAS

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS, for my homework I need to read this file:
http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Books.txt

I am trying the following:

```
DATA books_data;
   INFILE books firstobs=2;
   INPUT year numberBooks words copies annual author;
RUN;
```

But the author field is not read properly, generating the following error:

```
NOTE: Invalid data for author in line 2 28-32.
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0
2         2008 1 82835 668118 199514 "X.C" 32
year=2008 numberBooks=1 words=82835 copies=668118 annual=199514 author=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
```

I tried adding DSD to my command, as suggested in these links:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/readdsd2.htm
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/InfileOptions_ut.htm

But that doesn't seem to help (all fields are not read properly when I do that...).
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and sorry for the dumb question.

**Edit - My solution:**

```
 FILENAME books URL "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Books.txt" ;
 DATA books_data;
    INFILE books firstobs=2 dlm=" " DSD;
    INPUT year numberBooks words copies annual author $;
 RUN;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without completely answering the question for you, since you've said this is homework, you need to find a way to tell SAS that 'author' is a character variable. If you don't tell it otherwise, it will assume that all variables are supposed to be numeric and will throw errors accordingly.

Comment: FWIW, homework questions are perfectly acceptable on SO, including answering them in detail (though that's up to the answerer to choose).  They still must meet normal question standards (including not being 'do this problem for me'), but the above certainly qualifies.

Comment: And to elaborate a bit, the issue is not in the `infile` statement, but the `input` statement.

Comment: Thank you both - the HW is not about that technical part, though the hint helped :) For the readers: add a dollar sign ($) after a variable name that is of type string

Answer (score 1):

One good approach to writing `input` statements for delimited files is to start by writing a `proc import`:

```
proc import file="blah.txt" out=want dbms=dlm dlm=' ' replace dsd;
run;
```

That will generate input code in the log that has a lot of the common options set.  I don't recommend using `proc import` in production code, but it can be very helpful as a learning tool.